# Android Room library No response to update DB specified field / @Update not working

Tags: android, sql-update, rx-java, android-room

I am trying to update my database via Android Room DB library, but it is not working. Here it is my approach

1.This is my Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = TemplateEntity.TEMPLATE,
primaryKeys = {"templateParentUid", "templateName"},
indices = {@Index("templateName")},
foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = UserProfileEntity.class,
        parentColumns = "uid",
        childColumns = "templateParentUid",
        onDelete = CASCADE))


public class TemplateEntity implements Serializable {
    public static final String TEMPLATE = "template";
    @NonNull
    public String templateName;
    public int templateParentUid;
    public int templateType;
    private int level;
    private int time;
    private String diagramLevel;
    private String diagramIncline;
    private int someData;
    private int baseProgramId;
    private int useProgramId;

    public int getUseProgramId() {
        return useProgramId;
    }

    public void setUseProgramId(int useProgramId) {
        this.useProgramId = useProgramId;
    }

    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    private byte[] levelDiagram;
    @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
    private byte[] inclineDiagram;

    public byte[] getLevelDiagram() {
        return levelDiagram;
    }

    public void setLevelDiagram(byte[] levelDiagram) {
        this.levelDiagram = levelDiagram;
    }

    public byte[] getInclineDiagram() {
        return inclineDiagram;
    }

    public void setInclineDiagram(byte[] inclineDiagram) {
        this.inclineDiagram = inclineDiagram;
    }

    public TemplateEntity() {
        templateName = "DEFAULT_NAME";
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getTemplateName() {
        return templateName;
    }

    public void setTemplateName(@NonNull String templateName) {
        this.templateName = templateName;
    }

    public int getTemplateParentUid() {
        return templateParentUid;
    }

    public void setTemplateParentUid(int templateParentUid) {
        this.templateParentUid = templateParentUid;
    }

    public int getTemplateType() {
        return templateType;
    }

    public void setTemplateType(int templateType) {
        this.templateType = templateType;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDiagramLevel() {
        return diagramLevel;
    }

    public void setDiagramLevel(String diagramLevel) {
        this.diagramLevel = diagramLevel;
    }

    public String getDiagramIncline() {
        return diagramIncline;
    }

    public void setDiagramIncline(String diagramIncline) {
        this.diagramIncline = diagramIncline;
    }

    public int getSomeData() {
        return someData;
    }

    public void setSomeData(int someData) {
        this.someData = someData;
    }

    public static String getTEMPLATE() {
        return TEMPLATE;
    }

    public int getBaseProgramId() {
        return baseProgramId;
    }

    public void setBaseProgramId(int baseProgramId) {
        this.baseProgramId = baseProgramId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TemplateEntity{" +
                "templateName='" + templateName + '\'' +
                ", templateParentUid=" + templateParentUid +
                ", templateType=" + templateType +
                ", level=" + level +
                ", time=" + time +
                ", diagramLevel='" + diagramLevel + '\'' +
                ", diagramIncline='" + diagramIncline + '\'' +
                ", someData=" + someData +
                ", baseProgramId=" + baseProgramId +
                ", useProgramId=" + useProgramId +
                ", levelDiagram=" + Arrays.toString(levelDiagram) +
                ", inclineDiagram=" + Arrays.toString(inclineDiagram) +
                '}';
    }
}
```

2. My Dao for update Database.

   ```
   @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
   void updateTemplate(TemplateEntity templateEntity);
   ```
3. Update Callback Function.

   ```
   public void updateTemplate(final int templateParentUid, final String templateName,
                               final DatabaseCallback<TemplateEntity> databaseCallback) {
        Completable
                .fromAction(() -> {
                    TemplateEntity templateEntity = new TemplateEntity();
                    templateEntity.setTemplateParentUid(templateParentUid);
                    templateEntity.setTemplateName(templateName);
                    LogUtils.d("updateTemplate -> templateParentUid:" + templateParentUid +"/templateName:" + templateName);
                    db.soleHomeDao().updateTemplate(templateEntity);
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                         compositeDisposable.add(d);
                         LogUtils.d("updateTemplate -> onSubscribe");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        databaseCallback.onUpdated();
                        LogUtils.d("updateTemplate -> onUpdated");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                        databaseCallback.onError(e.getMessage());
                        LogUtils.d("updateTemplate -> onError e"  + e.toString());
                    }
                });
   ```

4.Database Class for  upadte.

```
 DatabaseManager.getInstance(getContext()).updateTemplate(templateEntity.getTemplateParentUid(),"test", new DatabaseCallback<TemplateEntity>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdated() {
                        super.onUpdated();
                        LogUtils.d("updateText ->  onUpdated:");
                        getTemplateData();
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onError(String err) {
                        super.onError(err);
                        LogUtils.d("updateText ->  onError:" + err);
                    }
                });
                }
```

onComplete is called, but the tempelateName of the Db field is not updated successfully.
Can help me for this issues.

Comment: How can I update the template name?

Comment: Please also format your "1. Entity" as code (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)